# JavaScript: query children and modify parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a static generated unsorted list and need to modify the parent li for a given child-href-match. This action should perform by rendering, not by interaction. I am using jQuery 1.12.4.

```
<div id="archive_widget" class="widget-odd widget-last widget-first widget-1 widget Archive_Widget">
    <h3>Archive</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://example.com/2018/">2018</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://example.com/2017/">2017</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://example.com/2016/">2016</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://example.com/2015/">2015</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://example.com/2014/">2014</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://example.com/2013/">2013</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://example.com/2012/">2012</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://example.com/2010/">2010</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://example.com/2009/">2009</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I don't know how to do this with JS, but this **imaginary JS** was in my mind.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var current = "<?php echo $current; ?>";

    var ArchiveList = document.querySelector('#archive_widget ul li').children;

    for (i = 0; i < productList.length; i++) {
        if (productList[i].text == current) {
            $(productList[i]).parent().addClass('active-menu');
        }
    }
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: If this should be done on rendering maybe is better if you place the class before sending the response to the client?

Comment: Change `.text` to `.textContent`. That should do it. BTW @Ariel's suggestion is much better.

Comment: `querySelector` returns a single node (the first found). Change to `querySelectorAll`

Comment: @Ariel Alvarado: the list comes from a plugin and should be just a visual help for the visitor where he currently is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems with your code:

1. document.querySelector select only one element, in your case the first LI
2. variable productList is never declared
3. The parent of a LI is always a list, not the LI itself.

Here is a working version of it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var current = "2014";


    var productList = $('#archive_widget ul li a'); // select all A elements

    for (i = 0; i < productList.length; i++) {
        if ($(productList[i]).text() === current) {
            $(productList[i]).parent().addClass('active-menu'); // Parent of A will be LI
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The "productList" was from a example code. This one works perfect. Glad (for myself) I wasn't thaaat far away ;) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, this would be set when SSR, but here's a scant attempt:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  let current = "2015";//set server-side
  let found = false;
  $("#archive_widget").children('ul').children("li").children("a").each(function () {
    if (!found && $(this).text() === current) {
      $(this).parent().addClass('active-menu');
      found = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active-menu { background: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="archive_widget" class="widget-odd widget-last widget-first widget-1 widget Archive_Widget">
    <h3>Archive</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://example.com/2018/">2018</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://example.com/2017/">2017</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://example.com/2016/">2016</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://example.com/2015/">2015</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://example.com/2014/">2014</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://example.com/2013/">2013</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://example.com/2012/">2012</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://example.com/2010/">2010</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://example.com/2009/">2009</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Why is everything red - while just ".active-menu" is declared as red?

Comment: The parent was the UL, I have updated to what I think you wanted

Comment: "this would be set when SSR" - what's SSR?

Comment: Server-Side Render(ing)

Comment: True. But I can't change the list (Plugin) otherwise I would have done it by SSR.

Answer (score 0):

Change ArchiveList to `productList` since that's what your code is using and use `.textContent` instead of `.text`.

Your query selector only matches one element. You want to match all of the anchor elements whose parents are a `li`, so use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#archive_widget ul li a');
```

Fixed Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var current = "<?php echo $current; ?>";

    var productList = document.querySelectorAll('#archive_widget ul li a');

    for (i = 0; i < productList.length; i++) {
        if (productList[i].textContent == current) {
            $(productList[i]).parent().addClass('active-menu');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @BrainBUG No problem.